Issues mounting and accessing Netgear ReadyShare USB drive with smbclient and CIFS
I've a Netgear router and the possibility to attach an usb harddrive for readyshare.
Netgear supports windows.
NetBiosName: readyshare  folder:media1
if i use Options:read all - no passwd, Write: admin
I can connect to the drive with smbclient -L //readyshare/media1
output:
    Sharename       Type      Comment
    ---------       ----      -------
    media1          Disk      read:all-no password;write:admin
    IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (readyshare)
SMB1 disabled -- no workgroup available

but smbclient //readyshare/media1, asks for a password (i didnt set one) and then a message shows up - tree connect failed: NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED
i tried to mount the drive with sudo mount -o ro -t cifs //192.168.1.1/media1 /..myfolder, but then i'm asked for a root password, i think, because only root has access to write, and i get PERMISSION DENIED.
if i change the readyshare options to:
read all - no passwd, write-all no passwd 
everything works fine.
How does this work with read only access. smbclient -B also dont work, browsing is not supported.
How can i mount the drive, and how can i investigate it with smbclient?
and how does a static cifs line look in /etc/fstab
